# Python nested dictionaries. Find ID with given key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I use python.

I have two lists with dictionaries in it.
From List A I need the ID of the participant to find a value in List B. In the lists there are dictionaries and I'm not sure how I can handle them.

I have accountId = 123123 and want to kno if he won the game (List B 'win': True).

List A:

```
{'participantId': 1, 'player': {'accountId': '123123', 'Name': 'patrick'}}
{'participantId': 3, 'player': {'accountId': '345345', 'Name': 'star'}}
```

List B:

```
{'participantId': 1, 'stats': {'participantId': 1, 'win': True}}
{'participantId': 3, 'stats': {'participantId': 3, 'win': False}}
```

So with the given accountId i can find the participantId in List A and search for it in List B and find if the participant wins oder loses.

Thx for your help!

Comment: What is your question? What happened when you tried to do what you described?

Comment: How can I check if a specific accountId won a game. In each game 10 players are listed (List B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a possibile solution:

```
dictA = [{'participantId': 1, 'player': {'accountId': '123123', 'Name': 'patrick'}},
{'participantId': 3, 'player': {'accountId': '345345', 'Name': 'star'}}]

dictB = [{'participantId': 1, 'stats': {'participantId': 1, 'win': True}},
{'participantId': 3, 'stats': {'participantId': 3, 'win': False}}]

def check_if_win(accountId):
    partId = None
    for dct in dictA:
        if dct["player"]["accountId"] == str(accountId):
            partId = dct["participantId"]
            break
    
    if partId:
        for dct in dictB:
            if dct["participantId"] == partId:
                return dct["stats"]["win"]
    else:
        print("This account doesn't exists")
            
print(check_if_win(123123))
print(check_if_win(345345))
```

The output will be:

```
True
False
```

I want to specify that you could use a better data structure to simplify this process.

Comment: thx for your input. I implemented it in my program and I managed to get the "performance" (win true/false) of all 10'000 games and export this information for further analysis! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = [{'participantId': 1, 'player': {'accountId': '123123', 'Name':'patrick'}},
{'participantId': 3, 'player': {'accountId': '345345', 'Name': 'star'}}]

list_b = [{'participantId': 1, 'stats': {'participantId': 1, 'win': True}},
{'participantId': 3, 'stats': {'participantId': 3, 'win': False}}]


def hasWin(list_a, list_b, accountId):
    
    a = [x for x in list_a if x['player']['accountId']  == accountId][0]['participantId']
    win = [x for x in list_b if x['participantId'] == a][0]['stats']['win']
    return win
    
print(hasWin(list_a, list_b, '123123'))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Starting point

The situation you have described:

```
# some dicts
a1={'participantId': 1, 'player': {'accountId': '123123', 'Name': 'patrick'}}
a2={'participantId': 3, 'player': {'accountId': '345345', 'Name': 'star'}}
b1={'participantId': 1, 'stats': {'participantId': 1, 'win': True}}
b2={'participantId': 3, 'stats': {'participantId': 3, 'win': False}}

# two lists consisting of dicts
A = [a1,a2]
B = [b1,b2]
```

You want to know how to match both lists based on the dict-values of 'participantId'. So that you can see the 'stats' information in list A, which is available in list B.
If that is what you want, I would loop through both lists A,B and append 'stats' information to list A

#### Main Transformation

Append 'stats' to list A, if 'participantId' matches for dict-elements in both lists

```
for b in B: 
    for a in A: 
        if b['participantId'] == a['participantId']: 
            a['stats'] = b['stats']
```

#### Flexible Queries

Now you have all information in a big List and can query your data however you like:

**1) If you want to know the 'stats' and 'player' information for 'participantId'==3**

```
[query1] = list(filter(lambda m : m['participantId']==3, A ))
print(str(query1.get('player')) + str(query1.get('stats')) )
```

Your print output will look like this

```
{'accountId': '345345', 'Name': 'star'}{'participantId': 3, 'win': False}
```

**2) If you want to see 'win' information, based on 'accountId', you can do like so**

```
[query2] = list(filter(lambda m : m['player']['accountId']=='123123', A ))
print(query2)
```

and now your will see an print output like so

```
{'participantId': 1, 'player': {'accountId': '123123', 'Name': 'patrick'}, 'stats': {'participantId': 1, 'win': True}}
```

or if you want to only see 'win' info for query2

```
print(query2['stats']['win'])
```

and you will see

```
True
```

Note: My assumption is that participantId is unique in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation of first answer by Guix could be using only one list comprehension:

```
list_a = [{'participantId': 1, 'player': {'accountId': '123123', 'Name':'patrick'}},
          {'participantId': 3, 'player': {'accountId': '345345', 'Name': 'star'}}]

list_b = [{'participantId': 1, 'stats': {'participantId': 1, 'win': True}},
          {'participantId': 3, 'stats': {'participantId': 3, 'win': False}}]

def hasWin(list_a, list_b, accountId):
    result = [win['stats']['win'] for Id in list_a if Id['player']['accountId']==accountId 
             for win in list_b if win['participantId']==Id['participantId']]

    if len(result)>0:
      return result[0]
    else:
      return 'AccountId {} not found'.format(accountId)
      
print(hasWin(list_a, list_b, '123123'))
print(hasWin(list_a, list_b, '5555'))
```

The output will be:

```
True
AccountId 5555 not found
```